# How do I change the font size of Google Chrome's address bar?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, linux-mint

I set my system font to GNU Unifont, because I like it's pixelated look. I scaled the fonts to the right size so they don't blur at all, however the font in Google Chrome's address bar is smaller than all the other text. How do I change the font size? Is it possible? (Complicated instructions are okay.)

Image:

[image: Chrome's address bar is too small]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what window manager you are using (KDE, GNOME, etc.), but I can see the tag `linux-mint`.

### Tab Font Size

If using KDE Plasma 5, you can change the tab font size via:

- Start Menu -> System Settings -> Application Style -> GNOME/GTK Application Style -> Font

However, this does not change font size of the omnibar.

In my Debian/KDE Plasma 5 installation, the default font setting was "Noto Sans 10".

Credit: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=154062

### Omnibar Font Size

You can change the omnibar font size (and all menus / dialogs / labels) with this command:

`$ google-chrome-stable --force-device-scale-factor=1.5`

Adjust the value (1.5) to something that looks good on your setup.

Credit: https://community.brave.com/t/adjust-address-bar-size/98884

Comment: `chromium --force-device-scale-factor=1.8` worked like a charm. Thanks!